# How to add a hyperlink to a object loaded using GLTF loader?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to add hyperlink to the object added using gltf loader, is it possible to add one in this code?

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    var mesh;
     loader.load('globe.glb', function(gltf){
        console.log(gltf);
        mesh = gltf.scene;
        console.log(mesh.children[0]);
        mesh.children[0].material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
        
        mesh.position.z = z;
        mesh.position.x = x
        if(x!=0){
            gltf.scene.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5)
        }
        if(y==1){
            mesh.position.y = x
                }
        if(y==2){
            mesh.position.y = -1*x
        }
        scene.add( mesh );
        
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding hyperlinks to 3D objects is not possible.

The common approach is to use raycasting to detect interaction with a model. You can then navigate the user to a different URL by setting `window.location.href` in JavaScript.

If you need a complete example that shows how to use raycasting in `three.js` for implementing interaction, have a look at [webgl_interactive_cubes](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes).

Answer (score 0):

As @Mugen87 stated,

> The common approach is to use raycasting to detect interaction with a model.

Since `hyperlinks` are typically triggered on click, use the `click` event listener of JavaScript.

Once you determine that the model *was* clicked on, you just set `window.location.href = 'https://example.com/`

That should do it~